# angular testing with sinon, mocha, chai

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I want test my angular app with mocha,sinon and chai.
Especially I interest in submit function. How to create mock or stub for LoginResoure to test this function.

Thanks!

```
(function () {
'use strict';

class LoginController {
    constructor($state,LoginResource) {
        this.resource = LoginResource;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.credentials = {};
    }
    submit() {
      let promise = this.resource.login(this.credentials);
       promise.then(()=>{
           changeState()
      }
    }
    changeState() {
         this.$state.go('home');
    }
}


angular.module('app.login').controller('LoginController', LoginController);
})();



    (function () {
'use strict';

class LoginResource {
    constructor($resource, API_LOGIN) {
        this.$resource = $resource(API_LOGIN,{'@id':id})
    }

    login(data) {
        return this.$resource.save(data).$promise;
    }
}

angular.module('app.login').service('LoginResource', LoginResource);
})();
```

EDIT:
Previously I do it with jasmine in next way:

```
            let deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve('Remote call result');
            mockPeopleResource = {
                createPerson: jasmine.createSpy('createPerson').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
            };
```

or if I want mock @resource

```
    mockThen = jasmine.createSpy();
    mockGetPeoplePromise = {then: mockThen};
    mockUpdate = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({$promise: mockPromise});
    mockSave = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({$promise: mockPromise});
    mockGetPeopleQuery = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({$promise: mockGetPeoplePromise});
    mockResource = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
        get: mockGet,
        update: mockUpdate,
        save: mockSave,
        query: mockGetPeopleQuery
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mock a service, you can create a test module when you set the mocked value:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  angular.module('test', []).factory('LoginResource', function($q) {
    return {
      /* You can mock an easy login function that succeed when
         data >= 0 and fails when data < 0  */
      login: function(data) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          if (data >= 0) return resolve();
          reject();
        });
      }
    };
  });

  module('app.login', 'test');
});
```

Comment: It is too complicate. With jasmine I do it much simpler. Look in edit